# Keras LSTM Binary Classification Output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am doing binary classification for a time series with keras LSTM. How could I extract the final output from the model? By this I mean, how can I get a list containing zero and one values from the final model?

Comment: what exactly are you doing? how does the output of what your are doing look like at the moment?

Comment: I guess your model has a sigmoid as output activation? Then you can simply apply a rounding function (and cast to int) on the predictions to get a sequence of 0/1.

Comment: Basically I am trying to predict whether the price of a stock index is going to go up or down. So that is why it is a binary classification problem. I want to get a list containing 0 (down) or 1 (up) for every timestep.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach right after a `LSTM` layer a `Dense` layer with as much neurons as you consider (that depends upon the `LSTM` output itself), and on top of that one add a final `Dense` classification layer with a single neuron, that'd be the binary output.